# Reclaiming a thread's memory in C++ with POSIX

Tags: c++

I have two classes, C1 and C2. Both are inherited from a Thread class (using POSIX). I call a particular function in C1 based on some socket request. I'm doing the following:

**C1.cpp:**

```
C2 *c2 = new C2();

if (c2->MyFunction())     // MyFunction will start thread, run and do some database activity ,ftp ..etc
{
    cout << "success";
    enter code here
}
else
{
    cout << "failed";
}
```

How do I reclaim `c2`'s memory here?

Comment: A class cannot be multithreaded. That makes no sense. It's like saying that you have a left-wing apple tree.

Comment: Kerrek, I have rephrased my statement

Comment: _"How to reclaim `c2` memory here?"_ `delete c2;`?

Comment: in C++ you reclaim resources using `delete`, i.e. `delete c2`. Is there some reason you can't do that here?

Comment: c2 memory is still being used by thread until and unless thread finishes its said task we cannot delete c2, there will coredump if we delete prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
void C2::ThreadMain()
{
    // ....
    delete this;
    return;
}
```

Be careful, since the `C2` thread is an implementation detail, other code should not assume anything about the lifetime of `C2` objects.

Comment: can you please put some more light on your suggestion.What is ThreadMain ? whta is C class ? ..etc

Comment: `C2::ThreadMain()` is the function directly run by the thread you mentioned. `C` was a typo, now fixed.